# What is the equivalent of isset for object's methods in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter application I use session class in some controllers (Not all of them) and I have fixed theme view rendered in all page. I'd like to use `session->setflash()` in the view. So, for controllers that don't use session I have to check if the `session->flashdata()` is set or available or not. I have tried the follwoing:

```
<?php if (isset($this->session->flashdata('msg'))):;?>
```

It returned the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you
>   can use "null !== func()" instead)

When I tried the suggestion of the message:

```
<?php if (null !== $this->session->flashdata('msg')):;?>
```

I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function flashdata() on a non-object
>   in...

Beside a codeIgniter error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$session
>
> Filename: themes/head.php
>
> Line Number: 44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your controller is always loading `$this->load->library('session');`

Then you'd be able to just check `if($this->session->flashdata('msg')){/*do stuff*/}`

Otherwise you could use `method_exists()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

```
if(method_exists('CI_Session', 'flashdata') && $this->session->flashdata('msg')){
    echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
}
```